# How to install Tex in Ubuntu... for a newbie

Tags: texlive, texmaker

Im trying to install texlive or any tex editor..
I will be using it for document preparation for my coursework.
could anybody give me a step by step way to install any kind of tex on my Ubuntu system? I basically want an editor where I can

- have a preview of my commands
- where i can easily edit math equations
  and symbols
- friendly to use

this is from my terminal

> Blockquote
>   ~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package texlive-full
>   ~$ sudo apt-get install texmaker
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package texmaker

Comment: For starters, see [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) Also, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Do a `sudo apt-get update` and try again. If it does not work try the process described in the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-for-all-packages

Comment: @Voigt I followed the procedure in the link you gave. I get errors like this:W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you want any kind of TeX, I would personally recommend using [Kile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kile), as it comes installed with all the packages and is quite easy to use. Furthermore it comes with a lot of tools like wizards for tables or tools to easily create equations and add symbols for beginners. It also has a function to preview your equations.

You can find it in the Software Center.

[image]

Alternatively you can of course also use your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kile
```

That's all you have to do. Once you installed the editor, you should be able to just use it without anything additional.

Comment: this is what i get...sudo apt-get install kline
[sudo] password for system:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kline

Comment: @user59288 you have a typo, it's `kile` but you wrote `kline`. Just copy the command as I posted it.

Comment: oops..but I get the same error.. I tried installing random software using software-centre but im unable to do it.

Comment: It seems like you have a problem with your Ubuntu. You should try using the link Rüdiger Voigt gave you in his comment. If that doesn't work, you might still get better results asking in [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)